# How to explain mathematically 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz WiFi coverage and maximum range?

Tags: antenna, communication, digital-communications, wifi, mobile

The question is why 5 GHz has less coverage and more susceptible to attenuation in long range? How can we mathematically represent how many devices can be covered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *why 5Ghz has less coverage and more susceptible to attenuation in long
> range?*

It doesn't.

The limitation you might be thinking of is because as frequency increases, the **receive** antenna size gets naturally smaller and, as the antenna gets smaller it naturally picks up a smaller quantity of the radiated electromagnetic wave.

Think of a receive antenna as a fishing net; a low frequency requires a longer antenna and hence it has a bigger net aperture area whereas a higher frequency receive antenna is shorter and it's effective aperture is smaller.

- [Aperture (antenna) - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_(antenna))
- [Effective aperture calculator](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/effective-antenna-aperture-calculator)
- [Effective Area (Effective Aperture)](https://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/aperture.php)

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: There are very important frequency-dependent attenuation effects, but they are nowhere near as simple as "more attenuation at higher frequencies".  They depend on the absorbance/reflectance/transmittance/scattering spectra of the materials in the signal path.  Biological tissue is a strong absorber at 2.4GHz, that's why that frequency is used by microwave ovens.